# ANOVA F Score for feature selection

Tags: anova, python, feature-selection, scikit-learn

so I am trying to solve a binary classification problem but I have 104 features on hand. I am trying out a filter feature selection method implemented through SelectKBest - SKLearn in python. I've used one-way ANOVA test as a scoring function and fed all my features. It spit out the following F scores:

```
[1.702e-01 8.922e+01 1.103e-01 3.737e+01 4.061e+01 1.083e+01 1.634e+01
 1.409e+01 5.768e+01 5.166e+01 2.117e+01 7.865e+00 1.902e+01 7.979e+00
 5.756e+01 5.526e-01 6.252e+01 8.374e+00 1.199e+01 1.390e+02 1.004e+02
 2.564e+00 1.276e+01 1.092e+02 9.470e-01 4.419e-01 5.748e+01 3.233e+01
 1.108e+00 9.146e+00 6.676e+00 6.303e+01 2.304e+00 2.251e+01 4.391e+00
 2.471e+01 6.652e+00 2.488e-02 1.921e+01 3.627e+01 2.497e+01 4.554e+00
 9.176e+00 3.316e+01 2.945e+01 1.653e-01 1.983e+00 1.122e+00 1.038e+00
 3.361e+00 5.888e-01 2.985e+00 3.243e+00 2.278e+00 5.970e-01 1.210e+01
 1.655e+00 1.592e+01 4.202e+01 4.554e+00 9.089e+00 1.514e+01 4.304e+01
 2.083e+01 6.310e+00 3.296e+01 9.856e-02 8.026e+01 2.338e+00 5.818e+00
 4.164e+01 5.184e+00 3.967e+00 3.575e-02 3.430e+00 2.764e+01 4.886e+00
 3.814e+00 1.696e+01 6.282e+00 5.541e+00 1.076e+01 4.166e+01 7.982e+01
 5.782e+00 2.564e-01 4.569e+01 1.024e+01 4.753e+01 2.213e+01 1.582e+00
 1.171e+00 1.859e+01 1.748e+01 2.073e+01 8.066e+01 1.977e+01 3.095e+01
 5.486e+00 1.492e+01 2.028e+01 2.456e-01 2.134e+00 8.540e+00]
```

Although, I know that I have to take the features with the highest score. It seems that the F scores were low in general. Does this mean that all my features have no predicting power at all? How do I interpret these scores?